# Formatting git log command

Tags: git

Is is possible to run some command and take the following git log message

```
commit 55dbd23f3802527cef5f9d3d5ea4dd3c69c72c5a
Author: Example User
Date:   Thu Apr 20 15:40:15 2017 -0500

    Here is the short commit message line.

    Here is the long commit message.
    This message can span multiple lines or have line breaks.

    Some more information about this commit.
```

and output it like the following.

```
Here is the short commit message line.
    Here is the long commit message.
    This message can span multiple lines or have line breaks.
    Some more information about this commit.
```

So if I have another commit following it that is just a one line commit message then I would like the output to look like.

```
Here is the short commit message line.
    Here is the long commit message.
    This message can span multiple lines or have line breaks.
    Some more information about this commit.
A different commit was made here. This only uses short message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do with git format alone is this:

```
git log --pretty="format:%s%w(0,8,8)%+b"
```

It puts the subject and then the padded body. However, as I understand git cannot modify body text, so all blank lines inside the body remain as is. So you could filter them out e.g. by using `grep`

```
git log --pretty="format:%s%w(0,8,8)%+b" | grep -v '^ *$'
```

Replace with tabs:

```
git log --pretty="format:%s%w(0,1,1)%+b" | grep -v '^ *$' | sed 's/^ /\t/'
```

Comment: This combined with mine that I have been working on `git log --all --after="$DATE 00:00" --before="$DATE 23:59" --author="FatGuyLaughing" --format=%B | sed '/^$/d'` should do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make the long message start with tab character instead of the eight spaces?

Comment: More specifically is there a way to take that command and have stdout understand tab characters?

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing I think git doesn't use tabs, but you could replace trailing spaces, i.e. `| sed 's/^        /\t/'`.

Comment: This just added the letter t to the beginning of the 8 spaces created by git. Also, having a hard time finding out whether or not stdout can handle tab characters.

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing Works for me in bash. Pay attention that the last line has `(0,1,1)`. If you see letter `t` it means you lost quoting, probably you need to double `\\t`?

Comment: Some `sed` variants interpret `\t` as tab, some do not. If you have one that doesn't, use a literal tab. (I like to set a shell variable, using the shell `\t` syntax `TAB=$'\t'`, and then do `sed "s/^ /$TAB/"`.

Comment: @torek Thank you that fixed the issue.